# Voice Bot Testing using Botium

Tags: chatbot

I am working on Alexa Voice Bot testing using Botium. As part of it, i have done the below steps as instructed in the Botium tutorial.

1. Node JS installation
2. Git Installation
3. AWS account created
4. Created Profile and got Credentials
5. installed ASK-CLI
6. Created New Skill
7. Deployed the Skill via ASK-CLI
8. Able to open Simulator.
9. The Simulator giving Json response of the Skill as a response.

Now my question is, How can i create conversation files(Test cases) for the deployed skill and how can i execute them using Botium.
How can i configure my Alexa skill with Botium to do End-to-End testing.

Please help, Thanks in advance.

Regards,
Chidvilas. K

Answer (score 0):

In Botium, test cases are called *convos* and can be written in [BotiumScript](https://botium.atlassian.net/wiki/spaces/BOTIUM/pages/491664/Botium+Scripting+-+BotiumScript), you can compose your scripted conversations using Text, Excel, or CSV files.

A very simple test case looks like this:

```
My First Test Case
#me
hello, bot!
#bot
hello, meatbag!
```

It's a simple test case where the user asks the bot *hello, bot!*, and the bot should respond with *hello, meatbag!*. All the conversations the bot is required to follow are written as convos in BotiumScript. To make it easier for the start, in Botium Box you can import the Alexa Skill interaction model to create the basic test cases for you:

[image]

If you don't use Botium Box, the interaction model importer is also included in the Botium CLI:

```
> botium-cli alexaimport --help
```

Comment: Thanks for the response Florian. I actually wanted to connect to my Alexa skill through Botium, open Botium emulator, do a conversation and save the conversation files in the Botium emulator itself just like we do it for Text based bots(like Google DialogFlow using $botium-cli emulator command). Please suggest me if we could save the conversation files in that way and also possibilities on importing conversation files of Alexa automatically. Please let me know if any queries.

Comment: Does the Live Chat in the Botium Box work ? You can use the "Save as Test Case" function there.